# C# automatic properties - is it possible to have custom getter with default setter?

Tags: c#

It's possible I shouldn't even be attempting this in the first place, but here's what I have so far:

```
public List<int> AuthorIDs
{
    get
    {
        var l = new List<int>();
        using (var context = new GarbageEntities())
        {
            foreach (var author in context.Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == this.BookID)).ToList())
            {
                l.Add(author.AuthorID);
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
    set; //compiler error
}
```

How would I leave the above setter without any sort of custom logic?  In the olden days I think you would just use:

```
set { authorIDs = value; }
```

which doesn't work now.

Is this whole idea just terrible to begin with?

**Edit:**

To answer some people's questions:  I'm attempting to combine MVC with Data Annotation validation, with default binding, with Entity Framework 4.0...and failing quite fantastically, I believe.

Comment: so you have a property which is calling a db? crazy man, put it in a method.

Comment: Your getter is way too complex for a property.

Comment: I agree with the two comments above, and is it really so difficult to just write the setter yourself?  The tings people worry about amaze me...

Comment: Plus how would you "set" this property? it's in the DB, would you replace all the records with what's in the value (List). A property should be related to a particular instance of an object (unless it's static, which this isnt), it should't need to "go somewhere else" to perform logic.

Comment: Pardon me.  I'm a total amateur.  I'm not intending to waste anyone's time.

Comment: I'm only trying to take advantage of automatic binding and data annotations in my MVC project.  I'm pretty far out to sea on this, in case everyone hasn't noticed already.

Comment: i agree with comments above but also need to add that if you must have such a complex getter, i dont see why you would need a setter at all. What is the intent here?

Comment: @PolishedTurd - not a problem =) we're simply highlighting our concerns. Bottom line, this shouldn't be a property, consider rethinking your design and seperating the persistence of Authors in a seperate layer (repository for example).

Comment: @PolishedTurd - chin up mate, you'll get there.  Its all part of the fun.  Ask questions, learn as you go, and don't let the bozos get you down.  (Not saying there are any bozos in this thread, just in general).

Comment: I appreciate any and all help I can get, trust me.  If nothing else, I guess I'm providing some entertainment and/or amusement.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins - spoken like a true Australian (takes one to know one). =)

Comment: @RPM1984 - Nice one, and the best city in AU too - good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer goes a bit wider than simply getting rid of the setter on the property - combine it with the rest of the answers and comments, and take the bits that make sense.  Hopefully the bit at the end will help too, maybe just not right now.

If you're using this in a model for data binding purposes and thus want it exposed as a property, I would do something like this:

```
public class BookModel
{
    public IList<int> AuthorIds { get; set; }
}
```

Make a service which you will call to populate your model:

```
public class BookService()
{
    public List<int> GetAuthorIDs(int bookId)
    {
        var authorIds = new List<int>();
        using (var context = new GarbageEntities())
        {
            foreach (var author in context.Authors.Where(
                a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == bookId)))
            {
                authorIds.Add(author.AuthorID);
            }
        }
        return authorIds;
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ViewResult List(int id)
{
    var model = new BookModel 
    {
        AuthorIds = service.GetAuthorIDs(id)
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

I explicitly haven't included how to instantiate the book service in the controller.  My preference would be to inject it at runtime in a constructor, but this will require you to have a custom controller factory - one step at a time.  You could just new it up in the default constructor:

```
private readonly BookService service; 

public BookController()
{
    service = new BookService();
}
```

In an ideal world though, I would do this:

```
private readonly BookService service; 

public BookController(BookService service)
{
    if(service == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("service must be supplied");

    this.service = service;
}
```

However the default MVC controller factory expects controllers to have a default parameter, so doing it with constructor injection will take a bit more work.

Comment: +1 for code example. Note: ToList() is redundant in GetAuthorIDs foreach loop.

Answer (score 10):

No, it's not possible. Either everything is explicit, or the whole property is automatic. Anyway, in that case the setter doesn't seem to make any sense... there should be no setter at all.

Also, I think you should make it a method. It would make it clearer to the caller that it performs a possibly lenghty calculation. It's also against guidelines to perform complex processing in a property.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what sort of method is recommended in this case?

Comment: Um, one that resides in a DAL?

Comment: "public List<int> GetAuthorIDs()" implementing the exact code you've got there :-)

Comment: @Carson63000: List<T> as return type is not really a good idea. IList<T> or even IEnumerable<T> is much better.

Comment: @PolishedTurd, see Carson63000's comment. However, you should avoid returning a `List<T>`. It's better to return an `IList<T>`, that way you can return another list implementation without breaking client code

Comment: @dtb - or better yet, ICollection<T>

Comment: @RPM1984, if you go that way, IEnumerable<T> is just as good ;)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque - you're right, of course (ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>). These things change every day, recently i have been seeing "use ICollection". What's next, IObject?? =)

Comment: So IEnumerable then?  Looks like I'll be learning a bit more about the Find and Replace feature...

Comment: @PolishedTurd: IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 4):

The default setter would create a backing variable at compile time with a name as follows:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private string <AuthorIDs>k__BackingField;
```

Since this is created at compile time, it cannot be referenced in your code until it has been created, and in addition, the angle brackets (intentionally) are not permissable in variable names.

For this reason, it would be next to useless to allow something to be stored in this variable (which is essentially what that automatic setter does) with no way of accessing this value at any point in the future (after all the getter here is not an automatic getter it would return something entirely different)

So to summerise, without a getter, there would (which is the only way to retrieve the value from this backing variable) there would be no point in having a private setter

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do it your way, just do the following:

```
private List<int> authorIDs;
public List<int> AuthorIDs
{
    get
    {
        var l = new List<int>();
        using (var context = new GarbageEntities())
        {
            foreach (var author in context.Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == this.BookID)).ToList())
            {
                l.Add(author.AuthorID);
            }
        }
        return l;
    }

    set{authorIDs = value; //this does not make much sense though ... what are you trying to do by setting authorIDs?
}
}
```

but just like others are saying, this is an overkill for a property, put it in the method, something like

```
public List<int> GetAuthorIDs(int bookId)
    {
            var l = new List<int>();
            using (var context = new GarbageEntities())
            {
                foreach (var author in context.Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == bookId)).ToList())
                {
                    l.Add(author.AuthorID);
                }
            }
            return l;
        }
```

Comment: What's the point of setting a field you never use ? Make an empty setter, or better: no setter at all...

Comment: @Thomas: just added a comment saying exactly that :)

Comment: I was trying to take advantage of the automatic binding in the MVC framework.  That's the only reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way of doing that:

```
public List<int> AuthorIDs
{
    get
    {
        var l = new List<int>();
        using (var context = new GarbageEntities())
        {
            foreach (var author in context.Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == this.BookID)).ToList())
            {
                l.Add(author.AuthorID);
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
    set{
       this.SetPropertyValue(page => page.AuthorIDs, value);
    }
}
```